# GORM : I inserted Data to Mysql DB but inserted empty value and null with golang gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

i try insert data with golang and gorm mysql driver but inserted value is null

```
var ipsin = ips{value: ipstr, org: org, country: country, city: city, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, isp: isp, asn: asn}

fmt.Println(ipsin)
//  result := db.Select("value", "org", "country", "city", "latitude", "longitude", "isp", "asn").Create(&ipsin)
result := db.Table("ips").Create(&ipsin)
```

thats my code
please help me

Comment: You must export struct fields, start their names with capital letter, e.g. `value` => `Value`.

Answer (score 1):

I think all data types are string and set mental primary key and etc. pls change it with your requirement.

you should do like below:

> your DTO like it

```
type Ips struct {
     CreatedAt    time.Time  `gorm:"autoCreateTime"` //optional
     UpdatedAt    time.Time  `gorm:"autoUpdateTime"` //optional
     Value        string     `json:"value" binding:"required"`
     Org          string     `json:"org" gorm:"primaryKey"`
     Country      string     `json:"country"`
     City         string     `json:"city"`
     Latitude     string     `json:"latitude"`
     Longitude    string     `json:"longitude"`
     Isp          string     `json:"isp"`
     Asn          string     `json:"asn"`
}
```

> create or change your table in DB

```
err := Client.AutoMigrate(&Ips{})
```

> insert your data into table

```
result := Client.Create(&Ips{Value: ipstr, Org: org, Country: country, 
                        City: city, Latitude: latitude,        
                        Longitude: longitude, Isp: isp, Asn: asn})
```

Comment: tested , not worked

Comment: Can i see ur code? I mean entire code

Comment: With new changes pls

Comment: type ips struct {
 value      string    `json:"value" binding:"required"`
 org        string    `json:"org"`
 country    string    `json:"country"`
 city       string    `json:"city"`
 latitude   float64   `json:"latitude"`
 longitude  float64   `json:"longitude"`
 isp        string    `json:"isp"`
 asn        string    `json:"asn"`
 created_at time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime"` //optional
 updated_at time.Time `gorm:"autoUpdateTime"` //optional
}

Comment: var ipsin = ips{value: ipstr, org: org, country: country, city: city, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, isp: isp, asn: asn}

 
 

 result := db.Table("ips").Create(&ipsin)

 /*fmt.Println(ipsin.id)
 fmt.Println(result.Error)
 fmt.Println(result.RowsAffected)*/

 //result := db.Raw("INSERT INTO `ips`( `value`, `org`, `country`, `city`,`latitude`,`longitude`, `isp`, `asn`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)").Scan(ipsin)
 resid := ips{value: ipstr}
 db.Save(&resid)
 if result.Error != nil {
  return false, 0
 } else {
  return true, 1
 }

Comment: Why u use lowercase?

Comment: Use value -> Value , org -> Org and etc.

Comment: Plz copy and paste my code to check it work or not